# Very very simple probability question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a simple question in probability which I solved in one way (I'm not $100\%$ sure It's right and I'm looking for another (more simple) way to solve it).

The ratio between the red balls and the yellow balls is $5:7$.

If there are $60$ balls overall, how much are red balls and how much are yellow balls?

My solution:

> Add $5+7$  you get $12$.
>
> Now $60/12 = 5$.
>
> now $5*5 =$ number of red balls
>
> and $7*5 = $ number of yellow balls.

is it correct?

Do you have another way, a simple way to solve it?

Thanks in advance,
Guy

Comment: Absolutely correct. And a best approach, there is no need to drag in algebra.

Comment: Without knowing distribution, yes.

Comment: Your solution is correct but this is not a probability question as it is completely deterministic.  No probability is involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set up the following equations:

$$\frac{\rm red}{\rm yellow}=\frac{5}{7}$$

We are given that $\rm red+yellow=60$, therefore, we have $\rm red=\frac{5}{7}\rm yellow$, or $\frac{12}{7} \rm yellow=60$.  Therefore, $\rm yellow=35$ and $\rm red=25$ using simple algebra.

Comment: Not sure this is simpler :-)

Answer (score 0):

therefore,yellow has=35 and red=25 using algebra

Comment: This is simply reiterating the last line of Justin Stevens' answer.